# How do migration of following code from Dotnet core 2.2 to 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, migration

Previously the code is written in **Dotnet core 2.2** like below, but I need to do migration in **Dotnet core 5.0** and the below code is showing error that is: The name 'BuildWebHost' does not exist in the current context. How do the migration without removing the below logic.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = BuildWebHost(args);
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredServices<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredServices<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(context, services, userManager).Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured");
                }
            }

            BuildWebHost(args).Build().Run();
        }


        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] arg) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(arg)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            } 
     }
```

Comment: Hi @VipinJha,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will solve your problem.

```
    .
    .
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    . 
    .

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationDbContext>>();
                DbInitializer.InitializeAsync(context, services, userManager).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured");
            }
        }

        host.Run();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configures web api configurations.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
              .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Hope its helps.

Comment: The code is same what I needed but, after using the same code it is showing the following problem: "IWebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Services' and no accessible extension method 'Services' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebHostBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#changes-to-take-advantage-of-the-new-code-based-idioms-that-are-recommended-in-aspnet-core-21).

So you need to change your code to:

```
 var host = CreateHostBuilder(args);
 //...
 CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

Then you can migrate.

[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

[Migrate from ASP.NET Core 3.1 to 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).